# Custom widget doesn't show

Tags: flutter, dart

I'am trying to create a custom widget CarteSim and I'am trying to call it everytime I click on Floating Action Button , but unfortunately it doesn't show when I call it inside the button , but it shows when I call it in the Scaffold , please who has ever experience that 
here s my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        title: Text(" INWI "),

      ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
        child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DropdownButton<String>(
              items: _type.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: dropDownStringItem,
                  child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                setState(() {
                  this._currentItemSelected = newValueSelected;
                });
              },
              value: _currentItemSelected,

            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            new Row(
              children: [
                new Text("              type client supporte * carte avec 1 cin"),
                new Checkbox(value: _isChecked, onChanged: (bool value){ onChanged(value);}),
              ]
            ),
          Divider(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
          new Column(

            children: <Widget>[
              CarteCin(),
              CarteSim(),
            ]
           )
          ],
        ),
        ),
        )
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CarteSim(),
              ]
          );
        },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
    ),
    );
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how tu update the UI in flutter

```
class FrontPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FrontPageState createState() => _FrontPageState();
}

class _FrontPageState extends State<FrontPage> {

  bool currentStateShowsThis;

  initState() {
    currentStateShowsThis = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final color = currentStateShowsThis ? Colors.blue : Colors.red;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        title: Text(" INWI "),

      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: color,) // alternatively you can change the widgets being displayed
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            currentStateShowsThis = !currentStateShowsThis;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In your example "the button" will call back the

> onPressed:

Which will only create the widgets in that method (**Column ...**) and not place them in a the layout.

Comment: but my problem is when I create a custom widget and want it to show while I press add button , it doesn't show @Durdu

Comment: I understood that but you need to put it in the layout in the same way I change the color from red to blue. You could change like 
final widgetToShow = currentStateShowsThis ? Container() : YourColumn(...);        .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      .        .      
see this line "alternatively you can change the widgets being displayed"

Comment: I see your point but this is a special case , just in one case , when you want to display just one time a widget you see what I mean @Durdu

Comment: I posted the second issue that I have hope you have an idea about it , I still can't move forward please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773580/trying-to-call-a-custom-widget?noredirect=1#comment101982935_57773580

Answer (score 3):

you are misunderstanding the process. The onPressed key actually used for call actions on press the floatingActionButton. You can write functions there, like you can update your state or print anything on your console or call an API to get data. But you can't display any widget from there.

Now what you're trying to do, that can be resolved like this. Whenever you press that button you should update your state, i.e bool show. Then modify your Column children based on that show state.

Comment: hi Eugene, my reputation was low to make a comment, that's why I put an answer. I hope you understand my situation.